# How to display UIView image slides and CollectionViews in two custom TableViewCells?

Tags: uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview, ios10

I am developing a simple commercial app in iPhone using Swift 3 and I am new to development. I have a ViewController with a UIView that loops through images with a UIPageControl. I also have labels and horizontal scrolling UICollectionViews in the same ViewController. I configured my scrollview using Storyboard and configured UIPageControl in code.

Problem: When I embedded a scroll view to the ViewController,  the UIPageControl and CollectionViewCells stay in the same position.

I have a sample here. Please see image for better understanding:[Image showing my ViewController where the PageControl stays same while the View is scrolled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voxiV.png) and another image of the [ViewController while scrolling up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDiYW.png).

So, I found that the scrollview clashes with my CollectionView and PageControl scrolls.

Can someone please tell me how I can embed my UIView for sliding images in a custom TableViewCell and the rest of my CollectionViews in another custom TableViewCell to enable vertical scrolling?

Here is my ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit  
class Home: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet var myView: UIView!     
    @IBOutlet var pageControl: UIPageControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()            
        self.addSlideMenuButton()
        self.title="Home"
        //Image Loop
        self.pageControl.currentPage = -1
        configurePageControl()
        slide = -1
        self.changeSlide()
        var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10
            , target: self, selector: #selector(changeSlide), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);          

        myView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swiped(_gesture:)))

        swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
        myView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

        let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swiped(_gesture:)))
        swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
        myView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)           

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    var images = [UIImage(named:"banner2"),UIImage(named:"banner1"),UIImage(named:"banner3"),UIImage(named:"banner4"),UIImage(named:"banner5")]    

    var slide:Int = 0          
    func changeSlide(){

        var loop : UIImageView!            
        loop = UIImageView(frame: myView.bounds)
        loop.contentMode =  UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill          

        if(slide == images.count-1)
        {
            slide=0
            loop.image = images[slide]
            self.pageControl.currentPage=slide
        }
        else
        {
            slide+=1
            loop.image = images[slide]
            self.pageControl.currentPage=slide
        }
            loop.layer.affineTransform()
        myView.addSubview(loop)            
    }


    @IBAction func pageChange(_ sender: AnyObject) {        
    }

    func swiped(_gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        var loop : UIImageView!
        loop = UIImageView(frame: myView.bounds)
        loop.contentMode =  UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill
        loop.image = images[slide]
        myView.addSubview(loop)

        if let swipeGesture = _gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

            switch swipeGesture.direction {

            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right :

                 // decrease index first
                 // check if index is in range

                if (slide == 0) {

                    slide = images.count-1
                    loop.image = images[slide]
                    self.pageControl.currentPage = slide
                }

                else
                {

                    slide-=1
                    loop.image = images[slide]
                    self.pageControl.currentPage = slide

                }

            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:


                // increase index first
                // check if index is in range

                if (slide == images.count-1) {

                    slide = 0
                    loop.image = images[slide]
                    self.pageControl.currentPage = slide
                }
                else{
                    slide+=1
                    loop.image = images[slide]
                    self.pageControl.currentPage = slide
                }                   
            default:
                break //stops the code/codes nothing.

           }
        }

    }

    func configurePageControl() {
        self.pageControl.numberOfPages = images.count
        self.pageControl.currentPage = slide
        self.pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.red
        self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.gray
        self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.green  

        self.myView.addSubview(pageControl)

        self.view.addSubview(pageControl)
    }        
}
```

This contains code for UIView image loop and UIPageControl also with the option to swipe through images.

Can someone please help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is how i did this: **
 Step 1: -
   First you need to create custom cell. Here is the code for custom cell:

```
class MovieCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var moviePoster = UIImageView()
var view: UIView = UIView()
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    contentView.addSubview(moviePoster)
    moviePoster.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    moviePoster.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let constraints : [NSLayoutConstraint] = [

        moviePoster.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
        moviePoster.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
        moviePoster.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
        moviePoster.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
    ]
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}    
}
```

This will set your image to image view. I have used anchors as per swift 3.

Step 2 :- 
  Create tableView in which swipeView is the view which will be set to headerView of tableView. add collectionView in swipeView as its subview.
After that set swapView to the headerView of the tableView and do pageControl settings. Here is the code :

```
 var tableView : UITableView = UITableView(
    frame: CGRect.zero,
    style: .grouped
)
var swipeView : UIView = UIView()
var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
var indicator = MyIndicator()
var pageControl : UIPageControl = UIPageControl()
var detailsViewVM : DetailsViewViewModel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)

    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.register(
        DetailsCustomTableViewCell.self,
        forCellReuseIdentifier: "textCell"
    )
    self.tableView.register(
        StarRatingCell.self,
        forCellReuseIdentifier: "starRatingCell"
    )
    self.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 //   self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(netHex:  0x90caf9 )
    self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)

    let tableViewConstraints : [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
        self.tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        self.tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        self.tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        self.tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
    ]
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(tableViewConstraints)

// MARK : Collection view layout

    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

    self.myCollectionView = UICollectionView(
        frame: CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: self.view.bounds.width,
            height: 200),
        collectionViewLayout: layout
    )

    self.myCollectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
    self.myCollectionView.dataSource = self
    self.myCollectionView.delegate = self

    self.myCollectionView.register(
        MovieCollectionViewCell.self,
        forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell"
    )
    self.swipeView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 200))
    self.myCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    indicator.StartActivityIndicator(obj: self.myCollectionView)
    self.swipeView.addSubview(myCollectionView)
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.swipeView

// MARK : UIPageControl

    configurePageControl()
    self.pageControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.pageControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: swipeView.bottomAnchor, constant : 8).isActive = true
    self.pageControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: swipeView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    self.pageControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
    self.pageControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.swipeView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    self.pageControl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.swipeView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

}

func configurePageControl() {
        self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
        self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor(netHex : 0xd6eaf8 )
        self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor(netHex: 0xd81b60 )
        self.swipeView.addSubview(pageControl)
        swipeView.bringSubview(toFront: pageControl)
    }

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let x = myCollectionView.contentOffset.x
    let w = myCollectionView.bounds.size.width
    self.pageControl.currentPage = Int(ceil(x/w))
}

func reloadView() {
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = self.detailsViewVM.getMoviePosterArray().count
    self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
    indicator.StopActivityIndicator()
}

extension DetailsViewController:  UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
{

    return 0.0
}

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {

        return CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.myCollectionView.bounds.height)
    }
}
```

Hope this answer will solve your problem.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. Yes your answer helps. However, I am new to this and have some doubts. What is MyIndicator and DetailsViewViewModel! and why use it? Also could you please post the full code for my better understanding? Especially TableViewCell class code also for textCell and starRatingCell.

Comment: txtCell is text cell in rest of tableView and starRatingCell is rating cell for my movies application. txtCell cell is same as MovieCollectionViewCell only difference is that its tableViewCell and  instead of UIImageView there is UIlabel.
For code check out [my upcoming movies project](https://github.com/PravinNagargoje/movies)